# What does "Weichspülmusik" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, music

Some people I have to do with frequently call music that plays in radio "Weichspülmusik", like

> Diese Weichspülmusik möchte ich jetzt nicht hören.

I always wonder what that means. Can anyone please clarify?

Comment: Softrock, but without Rock.

Comment: *Elevator music*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In German *"Weichspüler"* is a fabric conditioner. In TV commercials they always have a very smooth and soft music to underline the softness of fabric after being treated with their product.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FqjaHlv0Gj4) is an example for this.

Whenever people refer to *"Weichspülmusik"* they mean this kind of mainstream but very soft music. Another saying for similar music is *"Kaufhausmusik"* (music being played in shopping centers to make people buy more) and *"Fahrstuhlmusik"* (elevator music).

Comment: There's a wonderful term for "Kaufhausmusik" and especially "Fahrstuhlmusik" in English: Muzak.

Comment: Sehr lehrreich, vielen Dank. Und jetzt kenne ich den Weichspüler "Lenor"![Wahrscheinlich wird er in Frankreich unter einem anderen Namen verkauft...]

Comment: ["Muzak"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_music) is a related english term.

Comment: Muzak is a trademark. Elevator music is the most common non-trademark term for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muzak_Holdings

Comment: @hippietrail: I know, it's just that I heard the term Muzak many times when referring to this *kind* of music (and not specifically to a Muzak Holdings product). Usually in some comedic setting where someone is using the term to set the mood or make fun of it. It may even be a [genericized trademark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genericized_trademark).

Comment: @Joachim: Yes I think most people learn the generic sense of muzak before the learn it's a trademark as did I. Still it's worth warning people depending on what context they may wish to use it in English.

Comment: I would agree with Tomalak Geret'kal that "Weichspülmusik" is referred to almost every pop music in Germany - at least by a lot of people I know. So while the basic meaning may be similar to "Elevator music", what people actually consider to be it may differ a lot.

Comment: I already heard Janis Joplin in a Supermarket.

Comment: @user unknown: but Janis Joplin is never ever "Weichspülmusik" ;)

Comment: Yes - that's why I mentioned it here.

Comment: "music being played in shopping centers to make people buy more" - actually no. It's just to calm down and stay longer.

Comment: +1 for Fahrstuhlmusik. Reminds me of "The Girl from Ipanema", played in the elevator in "The Blues Brothers".

Comment: I think "Fahrstuhlmusik" can be associated with fun and swing and groove, whereas "Weichspülermusik" is almost always meant in a negative way, meaning that every edge or individuality is removed.

Comment: E.g. I would not call the "Girl from Ipanema" Weichspülermusik.

Comment: @donquixote In the Blues Brothers elevator verision you would, wouldn't you?

Comment: I am not at all convinced of the etymology surmised here. Do you have any references that support the claim that the term "Weichspülmusik" found its way to music played in shopping centres via fabric conditioner ads?

Answer (score 7):

The word literally means "fluffy music".

A Google search doesn't reveal anything explicit, but it looks to me like it refers to cheap, happy, pop music with little substance but high sales value. Think X Factor exports.

Answer (score 1):

Manchmal meinen die Leute allerdings auch, dass die Musik etwas unterschwellig vermittelt (Brain-Wash).

Comment: Interesting secondary meaning!

Comment: Gibt es dafür deutliche Belege?

Answer (score 0):

For me everything outside *heavy metal* is "Weichspülmusik". It is also a question of personal music taste. For some is this or that music genre great music, for others the same genre *Weichspülmusik* or simply *Weichspüler*

Comment: Hi Thomas! Willkommen auf german.SE! Dein Beitrag ist eher eine Antwort darauf, was du als Weichspülmusik empfindest. Relevanter ist hier, was das Wort "Weichspülmusik" bedeutet. Ist dein Beitrag mehr als ein bloßer Meinungsbeitrag? Das lässt sich gegenwärtig nicht so richtig erkennen.